# Is it possible to invoke one internal proc from another in Tcl?

Tags: linux, button, tcl, invoke, proc

This question occurred to me when I had to make changes to the source code of a Tk. Where, there was only one `proc` when invoked brought the result to a`frame` widget.

However, due to improvements in the internal code, this has affected the GUI [Tk]. In the way you presented the results, you now do nothing but press a button that calls the second `proc`. And this second `proc` was put in the first, since the ready code made me see only this solution.

However, the two are linked. And what came to mind was that if possible I could invoke this second internal `proc` from within the first `proc`, ie the first has to invoke the second and everything is resolved.

Example:

```
proc one {} { 
  # your code here!
  proc two {} {
  # your code here!
  }
}

pack [button .bt1 -text "Click-Me" -command { one }]

pack [button .bt2 -text "Click-Me" -command { two }]
```

Around the illustration of the example, I will call both procedures/processes at the same time, just once, clicking the *one* `button`, since the first gives me the opening of the `frame` widget, then I will pass the call to the second. This second brings me random results with each click on `button` *two*.

Maybe what I'm looking for is to simulate clicking the second button when pressed the first, I think it would work too.

But I cannot ignore the first, as it contains instructions that serve the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example code is **defining** a proc from within another. This is possible, but the new proc will still be created in the current namespace, or in the specified namespace if the name contains namespace qualifiers. This means that it is also accessible from outside of the enclosing proc.

To invoke the proc, just put the proc name and any arguments as you would for any command:

```
proc one {} { 
    # your code here!

    proc two {} {
        # Proc two definition
    }

    # Proc two invocation
    two
}
```

Comment: Yes, all it works now! Here I solved it this way `-comand {one ; two} `
There is also another possibility. *Focus* on the window widget button. Similarly: `event generate $w <KeyPress-F1> -x $x -y $y`. You probably want to direct the event to the focus window [widget button], and the X and Y locations ought to be set to 0,0 if you don't have a better place (or alternatively use the -rootx and -rooty options and the winfo pointerxy command to use global coordinates).

Comment: I don't see the point of defining `two` upon calling `one` for the first time. Why not defining them at the same level (`proc one {} {two;}; proc two {} {;};`. This way, `two` can be equally used as a command callback without having to call `one` first.

Comment: ... besides, `two` is kept being redefined whenever `one` is called ...

Comment: True. There is hardly ever a good reason to do it like this. I was just showing that it is possible, as it was part of the original question.

Comment: If anyone really wants internal procedures, they need to use lambda terms instead.